# how to run document.getelementbyclassname() while using node js

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering

Im learning node js and i am trying to make a mega menu appear when hovering over a link in the header. I understand that 'document.getElementByClassName' won't work because of ssr but I do not know the solution to my problem.

Ive tried to use the dynamic import from the docs but dont quite get how to implement it into my code. Below is a picture.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpopw.png)

Comment: You are using NextJS then why do you want that functionality? You can do things directly in react. You can use base/menu components in react.

Comment: thanks for your comment I'm still learning the ropes, could u explain how i could go about this is you have the time?

Comment: the problem begins where you use `document.getElementById(..)`. If you use an framework like react, vue or in your case next.js you dont need this. usually the framework has everything you need to avoid manually selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the current version of nextjs, you don't have to worry about SSR when your page component doesn't load anything dynamically. Just leave the _app.js and _document.js to its default since you are a beginner.

create a folder called `components` outside of the `pages` folder. Inside that folder create a file named Base.js and paste this code

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from "react";

const Menu = () => {
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(true);

  const showMenu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHide(false);
  };

  const hideMenu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHide(true);
  };

  return ( <
    div className = "container" >
    <
    div className = "dropdown"
    onMouseEnter = {
      showMenu
    }
    onMouseLeave = {
      hideMenu
    } >
    Menu <
    /div> <
    ul className = "menu-area"
    style = {
      {
        display: hide ? "none" : "block"
      }
    } >
    <
    li > Home < /li> <
    li > Home < /li> <
    li > Home < /li> <
    li > Home < /li> < /
    ul > <
    /div>
  );
};

const Base = ({
  children
}) => {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    Menu / > {
      children
    } <
    /div>
  );
};

export default Base;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can import the Base component to every other component and wrap everything in those components inside the Base component like this -> `<Base> /*your code */</Base>`

Comment: Thanks for your help I went away and studied react and now everything makes sense. Appreciate your time